# NGINX redirect results in “DisallowedHost at /” Django

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, django

I have installed nginx on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with Django One-Click Application on digital ocean, I have this config

**settings.py**

```
# Find out what the IP addresses are at run time
# This is necessary because otherwise Gunicorn will reject the connections
def ip_addresses():
    ip_list = []
    for interface in netifaces.interfaces():
        addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)
        for x in (netifaces.AF_INET, netifaces.AF_INET6):
            if x in addrs:
                ip_list.append(addrs[x][0]['addr' ])
    return ip_list


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

when I run
**www.enterpise.online**

```
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'enterprise.online'. You may need to add enterprise.online' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

I try to modify this line in **settings.py** with

```
ip_list.append(addrs[x][0][u'enterpise.online' ])
```

nginx send a message:

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

***nginx setup***:

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/**...

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;

            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

}
```

I don't have clear, what is the next step to activate www.enterprise.online.when I modify settings have the same error. by other hands, my DNS is config ok

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with you django settings.  This error means that the IP that is being used for the connection isn't showing up in the [`settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS` list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).  Make sure your `settings.py` has a line that looks like:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ip_addresses()
```